# Configure which .less files are compiled by Web Essentials

Tags: less, web-essentials

In my project I have a master .less file which imports some other .less files.

I only need the .css file corresponding to this master .less file, but Web Essentials keeps compiling the other .less files to css when I modify them.

Is there any way to configure which CSS files should be generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's obviously not possible to configure it in Web Essentials.

I finally ended up using [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) to manage LESS in my ASP.Net MVC application.

Answer (score 1):

Sometime around the end of 2012, Web Essentials added the ability to ignore .less files that start with an underscore (_). So, if you don't want variables.less to be compiled, just name it to _variables.less.